# how to test Typography color style is 'error' from the mui theme instead of rgb value

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I display a Typography component with 'inherit' or 'error' color, depending on the context.

```
const theColor = myTest ? 'inherit' : 'error';
<Typography variant='bodyXS' color={theColor}>my text</Typography>
```

I would like to test the style is correctly applied in my unit tests, using the theme variable and not the rgb value, something like :

```
  const errorColor = theme.palette.error.main
  expect(screen.getByText('order')).toHaveStyle(`color: ${errorColor}`);
```

instead of

```
   expect(screen.getByText('order')).toHaveStyle('color: rgb(234, 60, 60)');
```

Therefore if the theme changes, the test will still be passing.
But I don't know how to simply access to the theme values from the tests.